# moving from Xamarin.ios to dotnet6 and Application Extension

Tags: ios, .net, .net-core, xamarin.ios

we are in the process of moving an very old application original started in monoTouch but it has been well maintained.
We have moved most of the main application across (with some scars to show).
but the application also has a shareExtention Applet how do you generate a project for a shareExtention ? is there anyone whom has done one and any hints or samples ?

Regards Christian Stœr Arild Andersen

Comment: This might be helpful: [iOS Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/3289).

Comment: I will investigate But I don't think It helps much, Sorry

Comment: If you solve it, you could post an answer here. That may help others with same issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have managed to Hack my way through it and I think I managed to get it to work.

Here is what I did.

I downloaded this Maui sample collection
https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples

In there is a sample project [ShareExtention](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/tree/main/iOSExtensions/ShareExtension)

After verifying that is did what I wanted I simply lifted the whole sample (extension portion project) and added it to my project.

I then went to the share projects *info.plist* and changed the **CFBundleIdentifier** to my bundle identifier.

Next I edited my main *csproj* file to add a relative path to the extension *csproj* file

```
<ProjectReference Include="PATH-TO-EXTENSION.csproj">
    <IsAppExtension>true</IsAppExtension>
    <IsWatchApp>false</IsWatchApp>
</ProjectReference>
```

after testing that I now had a share sheet in my app I started to gut the project removing all the sample code and replaced all the *storyboard,cs,resource* files with the files from my old xamarin project.

then I copied the important bits from my old *info.plist* and *Entitlements.plist*

Once I had confirmed that the code was working I cleaned up the project (renamed files so it made sense in the solution context).

> Now I just realised that I have ported year old code that properly
> needs some sprucing up but that is whole other problem for another
> day.

Regards Christian Stœr Arild Andersen

Comment: Glad you solved it! Good job!